# Why linux decides that standard signals have higher priority than rt-signals?

Tags: signals

> If both standard and real-time signals
>   are pending for a process, POSIX
>   leaves it unspecified which is
>   delivered first.  Linux,  like  many 
>   other  implementations,
>          gives priority to standard signals in this case.

Literally,real-time signals have this name because it needs to be processed ASAP,almost real-time.

But why linux gives it a less higher priority than standard signals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because real time signals are queued, so giving them lower priority makes it less likely that you will "miss" a signal.

Comment: do you mean that so linux prefers not missing signals to instant reaction to rt-signals? This is betraying the intention of rt-signals.

Comment: @cpuer: Try saying that on the linux-kernel list and see what kind of response you get :-).  Seriously, though, the simple answer is that POSIX deliberately left this unspecified, so I do not think your "betraying the intention" claim is justified.  And there is a simple work-around:  Do not mix ordinary and real-time signals.

Answer (score 1):

It may have to do with the fact that realtime signals are queued whereas regular signals are not. That means if two realtime signals are activated in quick succession (before it can be actioned), your signal handler will be called twice.

If that happens with a regular signal, one will be 'lost' (though this is easy enough to engineer around).

I think the intent is to keep the two types of signal distinct. An application built for POSIX.4 will most likely use the realtime interrupts for as much as possible, leaving regular interrupts for rare things like exit conditions.

In other words, you would no longer use USR1 for configuration reloads (as some programs do) but would choose one of the lower priority realtime interrupts for this.

The use of realtime signals gives you what you need for a proper realtime application:

- no lost events.
- priority order so application can ensure important things happen in preference to less important ones - I believe *this* is the realtime aspect, similar to ensuring higher priority threads always run in preference to lower ones.
- multiplexing of signals (sending additional data with a signal).

---

Part of the rationale behind realtime signals can be found in a whitepaper authored by *Michael González Harbour et al*, entitled "REAL-TIME POSIX: AN OVERVIEW". An extraction is below:

The signal mechanism defined in POSIX.1 allows to notify events occurring in the system, but is not completely satisfactory for real-time applications. The signals are not queued, and thus some events may be lost. Signals are not prioritized, and this implies longer response times for urgent events. Also, events of the same kind produce signals with the same number, which are indistinguishable. Since many real-time systems are heavily based on the rapid exchange of events
in the system, POSIX.4 has extended the signals interface to achieve the following features:

- Real-time signals are queued, so events are not lost
- Pending real-time signals are dequeued in priority order, using the signal number as the priority. This allows designing applications with faster response times to urgent events.
- Real-time signals contain an additional data field that may be used by the application to exchange data between the signal generator and the signal handler. For example, this data field may be used to identify the source of the signal.
- The range of signals available to the application is expanded.

Comment: I don't see the reason to give realtime signal less higher priority,the signal handler will always be called twice for two realtime signals no matter it's with higher  or lower priority.

Comment: @cpuer, I wasn't saying it was desirable for its effect on realtime signals, just that it may help for _non_ realtime signals. If a USR1 arrives with RTMIN, then you get another RTMIN, you'll call your usr1 function once and rtmin function twice (no lost event). If a USR1 arrives with RTMIN, then you get another USR1, you'll call your usr1 function _once_ and rtmin function once (lost event). Hence you may be better off processing the non-realtime signals first.

Comment: so linux prefers not missing signals to instant reaction to rt-signals? I think this is betraying the intention of rt-signals.

Comment: @cpuer, POSIX.4 was an _extension_ to POSIX.1 and they clearly spelled out the disadvantages to the non-realtime signals in that baseline. I read that as "don't use them except when absolutely necessary". In any case, if you followed the best practice of basically doing nothing in your signal handlers other than setting a flag variable for the "real" code to act upon, this won't really be an issue. If even _that_ small delay is an issue, don't use the regular signals (ie, block 'em all at program startup).

Comment: And it hardly betrays the intention, since you seem to have asked this question to _discover_ the intention :-) The prioritisation of regular signals above realtime ones meets the four bullet points shown in this answer and POSIX.4 _explicitly_ leaves the prioritisation question open, meaning they had good reason for that. As with the original ANSI C, the reason may be that it was simply already being done that way. Even your quote indicates that: `Linux, like many other implementations, ...`. But bottom line, I don't _know,_ I'm only positing a theory.