# When several signals arrive at a process, what is the order between the process handling the signals?

Tags: linux, algorithm, data-structures, signals

When several signals arrives at a process, what is the order between the process handling the signals?

What data structure is used to store the signals which have arrived at a process but not yet been delivered?

For example, from APUE

> Since the process group is orphaned when the parentterminates, POSIX.1 requires that every process in the newly orphaned process group that is stopped (as our child is) be sent the hang-up signal (SIGHUP) **followed by** the continue signal (SIGCONT)
>
> This causes the child to be continued, **after** processing the hang-up signal. The
> default action for the hang-up signal is to terminate the process, so we have to
> provide a signal handler to catch the signal. We  therefore expect the printf in
> the sig_hup function to appear before the printf in the pr_ids function.

As [order of SIGCONT and SIGHUP sent to orphaned linux process group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17769300/156458) says:

> The SIGHUP cannot be delivered until the child's execution is resumed.
> When a process is stopped, all signal delivery is suspended except for
> SIGCONT and SIGKILL.
>
> So, the SIGHUP does arrive **first**, but it cannot be processed **until** the
> SIGCONT awakens the process execution.

`SIGHUP` arrives before `SIGCONT` at a stopped process.   `SIGHUP` can't be delievered while `SIGCONT` can be.

Is `SIGCONT` handled before or after `SIGHUP`? The first quote seems to say "after", while the second quote seems to say "before" by "until".

If "before":

- How can `SIGCONT` be arranged to jump ahead of `SIGHUP` to be delivered?
- How can `SIGHUP`  not be discarded when `SIGCONF` jumps before it to be delievered?

Are the above implemented based on some data structures such as FIFO queue or FILO stack?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SIGCONT has special semantics.

*Regardless of whether SIGCONT is caught, is ignored, or has default disposition*, its generation will clear all pending stop signals and resume execution of a stopped process. [[IEEE Std 1003.1-2017](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04)]  Again, this resumption happens **before** any other signals are delivered, and even before SIGCONT's handler (if any) is invoked.

(This special “dispositionless” semantic makes sense.  In order for a process to execute a signal handler, the process must itself be executing.)

POSIX is clearer than APUE here, saying that ["[t]he default action for SIGCONT is to resume execution at the point where the process was stopped, after first handling any pending unblocked signals."](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04)

As others have mentioned, the actual order in which pending signals are delivered is implementation-specific.  Linux, at least, delivers basic UNIX signals in ascending numeric order.

To demonstrate all this, consider the following code.  It STOPs a process, then sends it several signals, then CONTinues it, having installed handlers for all catchable signals so we can see what is handled when:

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int signals[] = { SIGSTOP, SIGURG, SIGUSR1, SIGHUP, SIGCONT, 0 };

static void
handler(int signo) {
  // XXX not async-signal-safe
  printf("<signal %d>\n", signo);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int *sig = signals;
  struct sigaction sa = { .sa_flags = 0, .sa_handler = handler };

  sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);

  sig++; // can't catch SIGSTOP
  while (*sig) {
    sigaction(*sig, &sa, NULL); // XXX error check
    sig++;
  }

  if (fork() == 0) { // XXX error check
    sleep(2);        // faux synchronization - let parent pause()

    sig = signals;
    while (*sig) {
      printf("sending signal %d\n", *sig);
      kill(getppid(), *sig);
      sig++;
    }
    exit(0);
  }

  pause();

  return 0;
}
```

For me, this prints

```
sending signal 19
sending signal 23
sending signal 10
sending signal 1
sending signal 18
<signal 1>
<signal 10>
<signal 18>
<signal 23>
```

Comment: Thanks. (1) "this resumption happens before any other signals are delivered, and even **before** SIGCONT's handler (if any) is invoked." and "[t]he default action for SIGCONT is to resume execution at the point where the process was stopped, **after** first handling any pending unblocked signals."  Is "before" and "after" contrary to each other? What does "after" mean?

Comment: (2) "Linux diverges from a strict reading of the preceding POSIX quote, as the SIGCONT (#18) handler is invoked before the handler for SIGURG (#23)."   since 18 is smaller than 23, isn't it that SIGCONT and SIGURG are delivered in ascending order as expected in Linux? What does "diverges" mean?

Comment: (3) Since SIGHUP is 1 and SIGCONT is 18, shouldn't SIGHUP be delivered before SIGCONT? Why is SIGCONT actually first delivered to resume the process and then SIGHUP is delivered?

Comment: @Tim, ambiguity.  At first blush of the POSIX quote, I'd have expected SIGCONT itself — its user signal handler — to be handled last after all other pending signals.  It seems my reading isn't yours, however, so I'll update and remove my opining.

Answer (score 4):

The situation is probably confused by different implementations and by the introduction of POSIX real time signals. [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) says that real-time signals are distinguished from old style signals by

Real-time signals are delivered in a guaranteed order.  Multiple
real-time signals of the same type are delivered in the order
they were sent.  If different real-time signals are sent to a
process, they are delivered starting with the lowest-numbered
signal.  (I.e., low-numbered signals have highest priority.)  By
contrast, if multiple standard signals are pending for a process,
the order in which they are delivered is unspecified.

As of the old style signals described in "The Design of the Unix Operating System" by Bach (before the introduction of POSIX real-time signals).

To send a signal to a process, the kernel sets a bit in the signal field of the process table entry, corresponding to the type of signal received. ... the kernel checks for receipt of a signal when the process returns from kernel mode to user mode and when it leaves the sleep state at a suitably low signalling priority.

You can see some of the current linux data structures at [sched.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/sched.h). Looking at this I suspect that the old-style bitmap has gone, and a combination of bitmap and linked list is used to handle both old style and POSIX real time signals, but I have not gone through enough of the code to be sure of this.

Answer (score 2):

To add to mcdowella's response:

1) The specifics of "signal handling" can vary from platform to platform

2) In the specific case of Linux:

> http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html
>
> Linux supports both POSIX reliable signals (hereinafter "standard
>          signals") and POSIX real-time signals.

3) See also:

- [About the delivery of standard signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343871/about-the-delivery-of-standard-signals)
- [Why Linux decides that standard signals have higher priority than rt-signals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338302/why-linux-decides-that-standard-signals-have-higher-priority-than-rt-signals)
- [The Linux Kernel - Signals](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-5.html)